# restoring database using RMAN

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

If I have new data like new users and tables created after backing up  database with RMAN , in case of restoring database will the operation affect my new data made after taking the backup?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. RMAN is aware of that possibility, hence why it creates a snapshot controlfile before performing backup. Rman needs to access control file to map objects to be backed up, and as controlfile is always in use, snapshot is used for that specific point in time. When you restore a backup, you're simply telling oracle to place those files from the backup back, so you don't need to worry about your data getting overwritten.

Comment: sorry, but this is complete nonsesense

Comment: @miracle173, thanks for pointing out. I confused the snapshot usage, which is "RMAN creates the snapshot control file so that it has a consistent version of a control file to use when either resynchronizing the recovery catalog or backing up the control file." - Appreciate your correction and contribution to the OP question.